# Why Ubuntu Gnome needs access to my location?

Tags: 17.04, ubuntu-gnome, privacy, location

Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 requests to know my location after every boot. I never experienced such thing with Linux distros before. Can anyone explain why this is so?

Comment: Did you install a weather app?

Comment: There is one pre-installed. But I get your point.

Comment: It could be a weather app or program that associated with location to get it work, like @Jos said.

Comment: There's one Weather app and Maps that will need location access. But I think it's Weather app asking for location at every boot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 uses a feature called **Night Light** which uses user's location to adjust the sunset and sunrise time. It also has a weather application and `colord` color management tool which needs location access.

Check the screenshot below

[image: location service usages]

Comment: Night light is off

Comment: @sziraqui Please check the answer. GNOME Shell itself tries to use location (I think for night light) with other two applications (Color and weather)

Comment: Yes you are right, Gnome Shell is asking for location permission to enable the night light. Color is disabled and Weather app asks for location only when I open it